# xslt -how to increase counter for each nodes

Tags: xslt

i'm new to xslt. i have input xml below

```
<Delivery>
<Item>
    <ItemNo>0010</ItemNo>
    <Material>GB123SS</Material>
</Item>
<Item>
    <ItemNo>0011</ItemNo>
    <Material>ST435DL</Material>
</Item>
<Item>
    <ItemNo>0020</ItemNo>
    <Material>YY902TU</Material>
</Item>
<Item>
    <ItemNo>0030</ItemNo>
    <Material>AW999AA</Material>
</Item>
```

and i would like to get this output:

```
1GB123SS
2ST435DL
3YY902TU
4AW999AA
```

my requirement is to display (Item/ItemNo) as numbering 1,2,3,4 instead of 0010 , 0011 , 0020 and 0030.

appreciated if someone can give me some idea how to achieve this. 
thank you.

Comment: Use the `position()` function or `xsl:number`. Post some code if you want a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use position for this like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="Delivery/Item">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(position(), ' ', Material, '&#x000a;')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**OR xsl:number :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="Delivery/Item">
            <xsl:number/>
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ', Material, '&#x000a;')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thankyou, it helps a lot. Whatif i want to display the number as 2 digit , for example , 01, 02 , 03 , 04, 99 . I would like to use <xsl:number/> , is there any way to format the number to two digits ? i try format-number but seems like it doesnt work.

Comment: hey , i found the solution , i use <xsl:number format="01"/>.

Comment: thank you so much for the solution!! have a great day.

Comment: yeah that's `@format` will take care any formatting. If you are going with position then use `@format-number` like: `<xsl:value-of select="concat(format-number(position(), '00'), ' ', Material, '&#x000a;')"/>`